# mixed Hodge structure of general linear group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mixed-hodge-structure

Is there any literature about mixed Hodge structure on $H^*(GL(n,\mathbb{C}))$ ? I think it is a vary basic problem in mathematics, but there are no literature about it?

Comment: is there some specific question with a specific answer you have about this Hodge structure?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is literature about it, it is Théorème 9.1.5 of Deligne's Hodge III. He gives a precise description more generally for a connected algebraic group $G$. In brief: from general Hopf algebra theory one knows that $H^\ast(G,\mathbf Q)$ is an exterior algebra on a finite set of odd degree generators. Deligne shows that this is also true for the mixed Hodge structure: as a mixed Hodge structure the cohomology is an exterior algebra, and the generators are purely of Tate type, with the generators in degree $2i-1$ of Hodge type $(i,i)$.